# Looping Through Existing Cells to Find Sum Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel VBA project and am trying to create a script that will loop through all cells in column H that have a currency value and will add each subsequent value to show a total in cell M1.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Loop_Cell_For_Sum()
  'Selects Cell H2 as First Line in Data
   Range("H2").Select
  'A Do Loop set to stop when an empty cell is reached
   Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
  'Creates a Running Total in the M1 Cell
   Range("M1").Value = Range("M1").Value +ActiveCell.Value
  'Steps Down 1 Row
   ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
   Loop
End Sub
```

I'm wondering where I am going wrong with this? Maybe it has to do with where I am placing the code within excel? I want the code to run automatically within the background. I have placed within the sheet as an object (by right clicking on the sheet, clicking view code, and inserting the above code).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you much!

Comment: Why not just use `=SUM(H2:H1004000)` Sum will ignore te blank fields and there is no detriment when using sum for full column reference.  If H1 is a title then you can use SUM(H:H).  Again Sum will ignore any text automatically.  But @AshtonMorgan has given a good method if you really want vba.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. I guess I was overthinking it a little. That would be completely functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub addColH()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim counter As Double

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("H2:H" & lr)
counter = 0

For Each cell In rng
  counter = counter + cell.Value
Next

Range("M1").Value = counter

End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing is the OP wants this to run whenever something changes, this may need to be in a Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_Calculate event.

Comment: Thank you @AshtonMorgan for this solution! I appreciate it!

Comment: And that makes a lot of sense @ScottCraner. I think that's part of the issue that I had with getting some of my original code to run. I'm a VBA noob, but I've started looking into Worksheet_Change events and it looks like this is the direction that I should be headed in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@AshtonMorgan has provided a solution to my question above. However, as @ScottCraner pointed out, the solution does not update automatically whenever something changes.

I have modified this solution only slightly by placing it into a Worksheet_Change event for anyone who may have the same question and view this post.

All credits go to @AshtonMorgan and @ScottCraner for this solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rng As Range)
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim lr As Long
  Dim counter As Double

  lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = Range("H2:H" & lr)
  counter = 0

  For Each cell In rng
    counter = counter + cell.Value
  Next

  Range("M1").Value = counter

 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested it thoroughly. It should give you Run Time error '28' Out of stack space. Sometimes it may crash Excel also. Perhaps because of Huge Range involved ~H:H~

Comment: @skkakkar, you are right. It does return Run Time Error 28 until at least the first row of cells are filled. Afterwards, it does not crash excel but it does slow it down considerably.

Comment: Functionally, my reason for wanting to do this in VBA instead of just using SUM for the range of cells mentioned by @ScottCraner was to prevent excel from running calculations on cells that it does not need to. I understand that by looping through the cells in this way I am essentially doing the same thing, which defeats my purpose. Something I will continue to look into...

Comment: It may be possible if we for some operation disable the events and after the desired operation re-enable the  events. Any working on cells after worksheets change event immediately affects the operation. Since you have already accepted the answer here, please post a new question. May be I or some other more knowledgeable experts help in resolving the issue.